# &quot; expression in Linux evaluates to single quotes

Tags: linux

What does `&quot` stand for, in Linux commands? What does it translate to - I am assuming single quotes. Could anyone please confirm this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes `&quot` signifies single quotes only.